# adding total sum with floating points

Tags: ios, objective-c

In xcode I am utilizing 4 utitextfields for the following chart that the user will enter a whole number, chart is the following:

```
Total |   Win  | Place  | Show

34    |   4    |    5   |   3
```

My algorithm for this chart is the following:

```
-For total win * 1
-For total place * .5
-For total Show * .25
-Add the three totals into a new Float value (identified as, 
float totalTrackAllTogether)
-Divide totalTrackAllTogether by the total column (identified as, 
int trackTotalColum)
-Display the sum on onOffLabel.text
```

Here is the code portion that does not seem to work and crashes

```
-(void)trackRecordMath
{

int trackWinColum = [trackWin.text intValue];
int trackPlaceColum = [trackPlace.text floatValue];
int trackShowColum = [trackShow.text floatValue];
int trackTotalColum= [trackTotal.text intValue];

int trackWinTotal = trackWinColum * 1;
NSLog(@"%d", trackWinTotal);
int trackPlaceTotal = trackPlaceColum *.5;
NSLog(@"%d", trackPlaceTotal);
int trackShowTotal= trackShowColum *.25;
NSLog(@"%d", trackShowTotal);
float totalOfTrackColums = trackWinTotal + trackPlaceTotal + trackShowTotal;
float totalTrackAllTogether= (float) totalOfTrackColums / trackTotalColum;
onOffLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",     totalTrackAllTogether];
}
```

I seem to be held up when trying to multiply floating points with whole numbers, and displaying it through onOffLabel.text. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you add an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) and show which line its breaking on?

Comment: Where does it crash? What's the error message? Why casting int/float ?

Comment: Oh sure, it is crashing when I hit the button that calls the function I showed

Comment: i am not understand this think int **trackPlaceColum = [trackPlace.text floatValue];
int trackShowColum = [trackShow.text floatValue];** ? Is it necessary for you?

Comment: I am basically getting the number values in 4 textfields (chart) and doing the math explained in the algorithm. When I hit the button in my application that will call the function above, I get a crash at the function call.

Comment: @pLokie i understand that but why you convert string in float then store it in int?

Comment: @chirag shah Because I figured multiplying by .5 and .25, I should use a float?

Comment: yes then you can used it like this 
**float trackPlaceColum = [trackPlace.text floatValue];
float trackShowColum = [trackShow.text floatValue];**

Answer (score 0):

These is basic stuff which works the same in C, C++ and Objective-C. If you do a floating-point calculation and store the result in an int, everything after the decimal point is dropped.

Furthermore, by using float instead of double you get massive rounding errors without any benefit. Instead of

```
int trackPlaceColum = [trackPlace.text floatValue];
```

write own of these:

```
NSInteger trackPlaceColumn = [trackPlace.text integerValue];
double trackPlaceColumn = [trackPlace.text doubleValue];
```

BTW. It's a column, not a colum. And you will get a crash if you divide by zero. So check whether trackTotalColumn is zero or not in your code.

Comment: Objective-C will not crash when you divide by zero. You simply get an `NaN` result.

Comment: No he doesn't. It's a `float / int` expression which means the `int` will be promoted to a `float` before the division is done.

Comment: Correction - division by 0 gives `inf`, not `NaN`.